# How to decrypt shared WiFi passwords?

Tags: wifi, password, keychain, encryption

With the introduction of iOS 11 and macOS High Sierra, a new feature was added: Sharing WiFi Passwords.

[image]

This awesome and convenient feature comes with one draw back: The passwords are stored in Keychain encrypted.  From my decent knowledge of wifi networks, **macOS must be able to decrypt the encrypted key into the plaintext password** in order to use it to connect.

**How can I decrypt the Keychain key to get the password in plaintext?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The summary answer is that the password doesn't need to be passed as the authentication can take advantage of a derived value that combines the SSID and the passphrase into a longish hexadecimal string (or value since everything is a number in the end) and stores that. You would need to reverse engineer or crack that intentional one way process to remove the password component of the end product.

[Here is an article](https://www.idownloadblog.com/2018/01/11/ios-11-how-to-share-wi-fi-passwords/) that describes your question.

Alright, for example here is the password I used:  `SomeSnazzyPassphrase!` And here it is in the keychain after iOS shares it to a Mac `CEAF1EE4F3050D25F2EF057A66CFD4570559C95656450407136347B75960255E`

Before we understand how to reverse it, we must understand how we got there.

First of all we're using a program called `wpa_passphrase`, which is used in combination of your SSID and Passphrase, to generate that long encoded string.

This is how we obtained the large "password" above: `wpa_passphrase <ssid> [passphrase]`

For example `wpa_passphrase MySSID SomeSnazzyPassphrase!`

And we have the PSK <strike>hashed</strike> created to be `CEAF1EE4F3050D25F2EF057A66CFD4570559C95656450407136347B75960255E`

Now as wpa_supplicant uses an AES-based cipher, reversing that isn't going to be easy.  In fact,  I'm just going to go out on a limb and say it's practically impossible.

Comment: I am confused. you talk about PSK hashing, but hashing it is irreversible so how is the second device able to get the password and use it to connect?

Comment: And how do we go from PSK Hash to AES encryption.

Comment: Also do you know if the hashing algorithm uses a salt?

Comment: Sorry, I probably misused the word hashed here and I don't know the internals of the code as much as I'd like to to answer your question.

Comment: No, hashing is the correct term! WPA-PSK derives the PSK from the SSID and passphrase. This is indeed irreversible. See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/28981

Comment: @JBis The first device does not share, and the second device never obtains, the password plaintext. The PSK (Pre-Shared Key) is the credential which is shared among clients. Every client uses the PSK to authenticate whether or not it ever knew the plaintext password that went into crafting a particular PSK.

Answer (score 0):

Open the app "Keychain Access".

Search for the name of the WiFi network. You'll see it listed as an "AirPort network password".

Double click the entry to open the details for the stored password. Then click "Show password".

You'll be prompted to input your account password, and the WiFi password is then shown in plain text.

Comment: Again,  "The passwords are stored in Keychain encrypted.". They are not shown in plaintext.

Comment: @JBis They are stored in the Keychain encrypted, yes. As I described, you can use the Keychain Access application to decrypt and view the password in plain text.

Comment: Your question is perhaps formulated a bit unclear. Are you saying that you're asking why "shared" WiFi passwords are stored differently than a WiFi password you have entered yourself?

Comment: I know the feature you are talking about and I have used it constantly. If the password is shared with you and you DO NOT enter it yourself the password is NOT shown in plain text when you go through keychain access.

Comment: Ah, so now we understand your question. Can you provide an example of how the password looks in Keychain Access?

Comment: No. As the solution to this question would give you the WiFi password ;). It's 64 characters I think. All letters are capital and there are some numerical values.

Comment: Could you send one over thats not your real password? If not, when you say capital letters are these A-F, or do other letters than those appear? I.e. do you think it is an hexadecimal number? Have you tried base64-decoding?

Comment: It's hex format and regular decoding doesn't decode to anything meaningful